# Is there a good practice of setting default values in an constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, properties

Consider a simple class

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int myProperty
    ...

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            // some evaluation/condition
            myProperty= value;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, if I want to create an empty constructor where I set default values for the class properties I could do this either this way:

```
public MyClass()
{
    myProperty = 1;
    ...
}
```

or this way:

```
public MyClass()
{
    MyProperty = 1;
    ...
}
```

Both examples seem valid, since I would never set a default value, that doesn't meet the requirements in the setter evaluation. 
The question is, is there a best practice or doesn't it matter anyway? 
What would be the advantage of one or the other be (as I can't find any)? Is there some reference, where this question is adressed?

So far I have come across code from many different developers that use either or both ways...

Comment: There are votes to close the question due to it being opinion based. Also the answers so far are quite opinion based. The question, however is more about if it is just up to ones opinion, or if there is an 'official' answer to this..

Comment: As you seen in the answers there is no "right" or "whrong" here, everyone has his/her own preferences, which is why we vote this question as "opinion-based". Best answer IMHO is that one from LeBigCat, as he introduces on what that decision may depend.

Comment: not rally an answer, so I add as a comment. Think about exception handling. It shouldn't make a whole lot of difference these days but it might make your code a little more obvious if an exception happened in a property rather than a constructor, especially if the constructor is doing many things. That would be my preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both. But i prefer the first one. Why? Because the value that the property uses is directly assigned. For C# 6 above, you can use default value in a property directly without using constructor.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "<first_name>";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "<last_name">;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to set it as you done in first block.
For me it serve as additional fact of method is constructing object, not using alredy constructed. Also it makes me sure that properties is not called (they transform to set/get functions which results in couple of excess instruction).

But i believe that both variants are valid and maybe compiler optimizes properties to direct assignment.

Answer (score 0):

For simple data first method is ok. But on more complex data, you could have a condition in the set (depending to another variable for example, set { if (Config.TestEnv) ...} so if you directly set the private value, you could be in trouble.